# Is a rational of two measures a measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

Let $\mu,\nu\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be Radon measures and $\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)$ the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to show properties for the map
$$
  \gamma: \sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)\to \mathbb{R},\quad \Omega\mapsto\gamma(\Omega)=\begin{cases}\frac{\mu(\Omega)}{\nu(\Omega)} & \nu(\Omega)\neq0 \\ 0 & \nu(\Omega)=0\end{cases}.
$$
One question that I have is: "Is $\gamma$ even a finite measure?"

##### My attempt:

If $\nu\ll\mu$, the according to Radon-Nikodym there must be an $f$ such that
$$
   \nu(\Omega) = \int_\Omega f(\omega)d\mu(\omega)
$$
for all $\Omega\in\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)$. If $f$ could depend on $\Omega$, then
$$
   f(\Omega) = \begin{cases}(\nu(\Omega))^{-1} & \nu(\Omega) \neq 0 \\ 0 & \nu(\Omega) = 0\end{cases}.
$$
However, $f$ cannot.

On the other hand if we have two measure $\mu_1,\mu_2\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, then we can define a product measure
$$
  \mu_{1,2}(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2):=(\mu_{1}\otimes\mu_2)(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2)=\mu_{1}(\Omega_1)\mu_{2}(\Omega_2)
$$
for all $\Omega_1,\Omega_2\in\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)$. So it seems that I could write $\gamma$ as
$$
    \gamma(\Omega)= (\mu\otimes\nu_{-1})(\Omega\otimes\Omega) = \mu(\Omega)\nu_{-1}(\Omega)
$$
with $\nu_{-1}$ given by
$$
   \nu_{-1}(\Omega) = \begin{cases}(\nu(\Omega))^{-1} & \nu(\Omega) \neq 0 \\ 0 & \nu(\Omega) = 0\end{cases}.
$$
This seems to work out, when we can make sure the $\nu_{-1}(\Omega)$ does not blow up. So, consider a sequence of sets $(\Omega_n)_n$ such that $\Omega_n\in\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)$,  $|\mu|(\Omega_n)\neq 0$ and
$$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}|\nu(\Omega_n)| = 0.
$$
Am I correct is stating that $\nu_{-1}$ is a finite measure (and by extension $\gamma$), since
$$
  |\nu_{-1}|(\Omega_n) < \infty
$$
for all $n$?

NB: I phrased it as if $\nu$ is a Radon measure, but I am most interested in the case that $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Have you checked that when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint  $\gamma( A \cup B) = \gamma(A) + \gamma(B)$? That's simple algebra, nothing fancy.

Comment: I added an answer based on your comment. It is indeed simple to check. 

Not sure if the absolute continuity of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$ is sufficient though.

Comment: @KCd Please don't make cosmetic edits to old posts. It puts them at the head of the active queue.

Comment: @EthanBolker I was bothered by the misspelling Lebesque and just finished fixing them all except on the MSE page asking why the misspelling Lebesque happens.

Comment: @KCd I understand. I fix name spellings too - on new posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When adding fractions, you don't expect
$$
\frac{a+b}{c+d} =?\  \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d}
$$
which would have to hold for the quotient of two measures to be  a measure.

If you really care about those quotients, see
[Functions resembling quotients of measures](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-124-02/S0002-9947-1966-0197671-9/S0002-9947-1966-0197671-9.pdf). Your function first appears at the paragraph labelled 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

When $\mu$ and $\nu$ are arbitrary measures, the answer is no. To see that take two measures $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and a set $B\in\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $\nu(B)=0$. Observe that
$$
 0 = \gamma(A\cup B)-\gamma(A)-\gamma(B) \\
   = \frac{\mu(A)+\mu(B)}{\nu(A)} - \frac{\mu(A)}{\nu(A)}
$$
for all $A\in\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)$. This implies that $\mu(B)=0$ must hold, and thus $\mu$ cannot be an arbitrary measure. It must be at least absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$.